# Declaring Sets in Javascript with Variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

This was my initial code. Letters and and spaces in POST.message work but not question marks.

```
const msg = {
    to: 'form.data@mydomain.com',
    cc: POST.email,
    from: 'form.data@mydomain.com',
    subject: 'New Message From Contact Form',
    text: POST.message
};
```

I had to change to this code.

```
var msg = {
    to: 'form.data@mydomain.com',
    cc: '',
    from: 'form.data@mydomain.com',
    subject: 'New Message From Contact Form',
    text: ''
};

msg.cc = POST.email;
msg.text = POST.message;
```

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Can up update your code to show where POST is being set?

Comment: Can you also update with what error you were getting?

Comment: Please share the following: What does "won't work" mean? What are the values of `POST.email` and `POST.message`? Where are you attempting to use them that it "doesn't work", and are there any associated errors?

Comment: Also, what you've shown us here are *objects*, not *sets*. The only reason I make this distinction is because there is such a thing as a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) in JavaScript, but I don't believe that's what you're referring to.

Comment: Sorry guys. I must have fixed the bug inadvertently and now I can't recreate it and it probably had nothing to do with what I did above. *facepalm*

Comment: I think I figured out my "bug". I was calling res.end outside of req.on('end' and I believe res.end will stop the processing of the req.